# jquery copy to clipboard

Tags: jquery, html

I found a jquery that will copy to clipboard all values of a form. My webpage currently have 2 form id and when trying to click the copy button it will copy everything in the form.

Is there any way that I can specify which form to copy through their id?

Here's the jquery.

I've tried changing $(this.form) to the form id but to no avail.

```
$(document).on('click', '.copy', function(e) {
  var serialized = $(this.form).serializeArray()
  var text = serialized.map(function(field) {
    return (field.name !== "hidden" ? field.name + ": " : "") + field.value
  }).join("\n")

  $("#copy").show().val(text)[0].select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $("#copy").hide();
  alert("Successfully copied to clipboard!");

  return false

})
```

Comment: can you show us your form(s)?

Comment: What does it do when you use `$(this.form)`? Does it copy anything? Try using `$(this).closest("form")` instead.

Comment: I think I've managed to figure it out. Thanks btw! :)